# Unix Permisions: How do groups work in Unix

Tags: unix, file-permissions

This is probably a dup (but did not find it..)

When you type `ls -l` in unix you get output like this:

```
% ls -l
total 48
-rwxr--r--   ... change*
-rwxrwxrwx   ... checkVersion*
-rwx------   ... info*
```

I know that the first group of rwx sets the users permisions and the last group sets "everyone else's" permisions.  I think that the second rwx group sets the "group"s permissions.

How can I tell people who are in the group?  What group am I in?  Can I create new groups?  Where are the *groups defined on my machine*?

---

**Edit:** Can I modify groups by modifying the /etc/groups file or do I need to do it with a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know which groups you are in type

```
groups
```

on the console.

The groups members are listed in /etc/group

Answer (score 2):

You can edit group in `/etc/group` but it's really better to use system commands like :

- `groupadd` to create some groups
- `usermod` to operate on user and especially add users to group

Here is a sample that append `yoda` user to `jedi` group :

- `usermod -A jedi yoda`

see the manual of each command for usage :

- `man groupadd`
- `man usermod`

Answer (score 1):

The groups are defined in the `/etc/group` file.  You'll find a listing of the groups and the accounts that are members of each group there.

The unix `groups` command tells you what groups your account is in.

```
Hubble:~ $ groups
staff _developer _lpoperator _lpadmin admin localaccounts everyone
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the /etc/passwd file. it has your users. then check out the /etc/group file. it has the groups with unique id's

```
group-name:x:group-number:user1,user2
```